# JAVA DB: Shutdown Derby does not work

Tags: derby, javadb

I`m using the following method to close my connection to java DB:

```
public void shutdownDisconnect() {

    if(connectionExists) {
        String databaseURL = getDBurl();
        dbProperties.put("shutdown", "true");
        try {
            DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, dbProperties);
            System.out.println("success"); 
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
           //shutdown always results in an SQLException
            System.out.println(ex); 
           //This exeption is:java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE: 08006, SQLERRMC: Database 'databasename' shutdown.
        }
        connectionExists = false;
    }
}
```

My first `System.out.println` doesn`t print anything which means try is not performed, and I get above indicated exception.

As I know "A successful shutdown always results in an SQLException" but does it mean the try statement is not performed? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your `try` block **is** performed otherwise the exception would not be thrown.

Unfortunately that's the way the shutdown with Derby works.

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown at

```
DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, dbProperties);
```

That's why:

```
System.out.println("success");
```

is not executed.

```
System.out.println(ex);
```

Is printing

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE: 08006, SQLERRMC: Database 'databasename' shutdown.
```

so you see: the `catch`-block is handled.

If you add `System.out.println("success");` as the first statement in the catch block it will be printed.